# Emailing PDF from Access

Tags: email, ms-access, vba

I have just recently coded behind a command button to send an email of a form, but when the email pops up and I open the PDF file there are 15 duplicates of the same form. Does anybody know why this would be happening?

Thanks :)

```
On Error GoTo errhandle
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "email address", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
exitErr:
Exit Sub
errhandle:
If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
MsgBox ("Email cancelled!")
End If
Resume exitErr


Me.Filter = "CurrentDate= #" & Me!CurrentDate & "#" AND "Discover= '" & Me!Discover & "'" AND "Tail= '" & Me!Tail & "'" AND "FleetID= '" & Me!FleetID & "'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your form currently has 15 records. When you use SendObject on a form, it prints **all** records in the form, not just the current one, into the PDF. I think you need to filter your form to show only the current record, then SendObject. If your data source has a primary key field named `ID` use:

```
Me.Filter = "ID=" & Me!ID
Me.FilterOn = True
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", ...
```

If you have a multi-field primary key use:

```
Me.Filter = "ID=" & Me!ID & " AND CustName = '" & Me!CustName & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Use no delimiter for numeric fields, quotes around text field values, and `#` around date field values formatted mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: When you say "MyNumericKey" is this like the autonumber key each record gets?

Comment: @Brianna I have changed it to `ID` but you must name it with your primary key field's name.

Comment: Ok I got it now! Thanks :) I would just put an and between the field if I have more than one primary key right?

Comment: So say I have four fields that are my primary key: CurrentDate, Discover, Tail, and FleetID and CurrentDate is a date field and the other three are text fields. Would it look like what I added above?

Comment: I cant seem to get the code correct I keep getting a Syntax Error